# Why does only the last element of the array is shown in my RecyclerView?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

So I have an array with books which I display in a recyclerView but only the last element of the array is being displayed.

Here is my code:

```
 backendManager.getAllBookPlaces(object: BackendManager.MyCallbackPlaces {
        override fun onCallback(value: ArrayList<BookPlace>) {
            Log.d("VALUE", value.size.toString())
            name = intent.getStringExtra("NAME")

             value.forEach {
                 println(it.name)
                 if (it.name == name ) {
                     it.books!!.forEach {it->
                         var book: Book? = null
                         book = it
                         Log.d("VALUE", book.title)
                         bookList!!.add(book)
                     }

                     Log.d("VALUE", value.size.toString())

                 }

            // Log.d("START", bookList?.let { backendManager.getAllBooks(it) }!!.size.toString())
            rv_book_list.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this@BookPlaceActivity)

            // Access the RecyclerView Adapter and load the data into it
            rv_book_list.adapter = RecycleAdapter(bookList,this@BookPlaceActivity)
            Log.d("END", bookList!!.size.toString())
             }
        }

    })
```

Here is my OnBindViewHolder. I believe it might be something here but I am not sure what. 
**RecyclerView**

```
   override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {

    items?.forEach {

        holder?.tvBookTitle?.text =  it.title //items?.get(position)
        holder?.tvBookAuthor.text = it.author

        var ref =  FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference("/images/${it.image}")
        ref.downloadUrl.addOnSuccessListener {it->
            Glide.with(context) //1
                    .load(it.toString())
                    .error(R.drawable.book_icon)
                    .fitCenter()
                   // .transform(CircleCrop())
                    .into(holder?.imagePic!!)
        }

        if (!it.isTaken) {
            holder?.tvAvailable.text = "Available"
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I don't see the issue, but it could be in code you haven't shown. By the way, all the code in the if statement could be replaced with `bookList!!.addAll(it.books!!)` to simplify it.

Comment: Hey, thanks. I added some additional code which I suspect might be the cause of the problem.

Comment: Yeah, the problem is right there. instead of using `items.forEach`, use `item[position]`. This function is called once for each item as it appears on the screen. Since you are iterating the whole list, the last item is the one that is shown.

Comment: Yes, that was it. Thank you very much.